# When does freezer evaporator fan turn on and when does it turn off

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

I have a GE side by side fridge model GSS22UFPDWW.  This fridge does not have a timer for defrost cycle.  Instead it has what is called an encoder that sends data to the main board and the main board makes decision for all operaation.

I have not been able to find a straight answer to the fact that the evaporator fan the one and only fan in the freezer runs at all times.

As far as the condensor fan and the compressor operation go, they do turn off when the temperatures are within specification.
Everything else function as they should.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: An encoder on a motor is normally a device that provides position, on a fan motor it would report speed, air velocity and amount of cooling change measured is one way to calculate if there is ice buildup on the evaporator. Do you have a problem or is this just a question? We are not a discussion forum.

Comment: Ali . You used term encoder with motors this usually means what I stated. You said sending data this is what an encoder dose sorry you do not like what I wrote. But I gave an explanation on what may be happening. This is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal in many refrigeration units, it is a design parameter. Some cycle, some change speed, some never had a fan. It is based on the evaporator design and the performance requirements. With the fan running you will get better cooling. This also can help reduce the size of the evaporator.

Comment: Thank you Gil.  I suspected that it might be the case with this fridge but I wasn't sure.  No matter where I looked, it had no mention of it clearly.   I also had a hard time trying to understand as to what was the substitute in this fridge for defrost timer. That took a bit of looking.  It is what is termed as the encoder and not because there was any explanation as to what it had replaced.  Only when I looked that its location was in the same space as the defrost timer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to click accept and give you a thumbs upa year later I have.   I did not pay attention about various details of the system pertaining to stackexchange.